# Adding an Highstock time in HighChart Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I'am trying to implements a timer like there: [HighStock Timer](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/data-grouping/)

I already have some HighChart charts working in my project and i need to build some pie chart and vertical bar chart including the timer comming from Highstock..thanks in advance

Here's my code: (I tried to add "rangeselector" but i cannot see nothing 
in my view)

```
 export class MyDailyreportComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {


   //  @Input() showMePartially: boolean;
     @Input() displayDetail: boolean;

    options: any;
    data: Object[];
    chart: any;
    dataSubscription: Subscription;

     constructor(public userService3: UserService3) {

           this.options = {
            chart: {  type: 'pie',
                     plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,  },
   //     legend: { enabled: false },
            credits: { enabled: false },
            tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            allowPointSelect: false,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
     //      format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            }
          }
         },
       rangeSelector: {
        enabled: true,
        allButtonsEnabled: true,
        buttons: [{
          type: 'hour',
          count: 1,
          text: '1h'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 1,
          text: '1d'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 1,
          text: '1m'
        }, {
          type: 'year',
          count: 1,
          text: '1y'
        }, {
          type: 'all',
          text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: true, // it supports only days
    //selected: 4 // all
      },
            series: [{
              name: 'Dispo',
              data: []
            }]
       };
        }

   saveInstance(chartInstance) {
    this.chart = chartInstance;
  //   console.log(chartInstance);
}

    public ngOnInit () {
    this.dataSubscription = this.userService3.getData().subscribe((data) 
=> {
      this.options.series[0].data = data.data.operating_rate;
   // Code for the pie

        let percentUp = data.data.operating_rate; // 88.14
        let percentDown = 100 - percentUp; // 11.86
        this.options.series[0].data = [
        {
        name: 'Up',
        y: percentUp,
        color: 'green'
        },
            {
        name: 'Down',
        y: percentDown,
        color: 'white'
        }
        ]
      console.log(data);
   });
}
    public ngOnDestroy() {
      if (this.dataSubscription) {
this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
 }
  }
```

Here a screenshot of the probable view:
[image]

Comment: Can you make a fully reproducible example, e.g. on jsfiddle, plunkr? You can add a rangeselector for a pie series - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvttpjed/ - but it does not make sense because range selector navigates x values and points in a pie do not have x values.

Comment: @morganfree thanks for your help I update my post with a picture of what it should be at the end (the pie are in the left side of the picture an don't really need the range selector themselfs)

Comment: Do you load Highstock library? RangeSelector works only in Highstock. Your code is still not complete - see [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). On angular2-highcharts there is the demo angular2 + rangeSelector - http://plnkr.co/edit/2xSewTZ9b213vA0ALmFq?p=preview

Comment: @morganfree thanks I'll try this right now